# Stop VideoView from updating

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-videoview

My app currently plays a video from the internet without any issues, when I rotate the screen the VideoView turns off, flashes, is 're-created' and resumes the video from where it left off. I know previously `UpdateVideoPlayerState(false);` worked to stop it from flashing when it is rotated, but now that doesn't work.

How can I stop the videoview from updating when I rotate the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your Activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "App", MainLauncher = true,ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.O‌​‌​rientation|Android‌​.C‌​ontent.PM.Config‌​Chan‌​ges.ScreenSize‌​)]
```

It will avoid your Activity and your video view recreate when you rotate the screen.

Comment: I got this error 'The name 'ConfigurationChanges' does not exist in the current context VideoViewer C:\Projects\Programming\Xamarin\VideoView\VideoViewer\VideoViewer\MainActivity.cs. I don't get how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Write it in the ActivityAttribute `[Activity(Label = "App", MainLauncher = true,ConfigurationChanges=Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.O‌​rientation|Android.C‌​ontent.PM.ConfigChan‌​ges.ScreenSize)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can create your VideoView within a fragment. Set retainState in fragment's onCreate to true.
Inside fragment you can call setRetainedInstance(true), this way your fragment will not be recreated during configuration changes. Normally when you rotate your device, all fragments will be recreated. If you call setRetainedInstance(true) inside onCreate(), then your fragment instance will not be recreated.

Whats use of it? - you can put some data, arrays etc. inside your fragment and it will not be destroyed during configuration changes. You can also put async task inside such fragment, and after main activity rotates, your async task in your fragment will still be able to deliver its results.

Another usefull feature of fragments is that you can easily reuse them in multiple activities.